# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName')

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, model-view-controller, xhtml

I've written some Ajax MVC code, which I'm now trying to deploy to Google App Engine. The code runs absolutely fine in the browser on localhost, with both Tomcat and Google App Engine. When I deploy the code to App Engine on Google Cloud however, I get a TypeError in browser (Safari & Chrome).

If it's helpful, the error message in browser specifically points to two JS functions:

*getXmlValues & showXmlCustomerInfo*

I've added the XHTML, JS and JSP code below. There's also Java classes for the model beans and web servlet, which I can add if needed, but I'm assuming the problem lies somewhere between the form and the js.

I should also point out that the js functions have been provided, so I haven't written any of those.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance...

**XHTML Form**

```
<head>
  <title>Ajax Lab 2</title>

  <link
     rel="stylesheet"       
     href="resources/css/styles.css"
     type="text/css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" bgcolor="gray">
        <tr><th><big></big>Ajax Lab 2, Exercise 1</th></tr>
    </table>
    <p/>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Push button with inner HTML/JSP update, sending content as XML</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="button" value="Richest Two Customers"
            onclick="xmlCustomerTable('result')"/>
        </form>
        <script
                src="resources/js/ajax_utils.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
        <p/>
        <div id="result"></div>
        
    </fieldset>
    <br/>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function xmlCustomerTable(resultRegion) {
    let address = "two-richest-customers";          
    let data = "format=";

    ajaxPost(address, data,                         
        function (request) {
            showXmlCustomerInfo(request, resultRegion)
        });
}

function ajaxPost(address, data, responseHandler) {
    let request = getRequestObject();
    request.onreadystatechange =
        function () { responseHandler(request); };
    request.open("POST", address, true);
    request.setRequestHeader(
        "Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(data);
}

function getRequestObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return(new XMLHttpRequest());
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    } else {
        return(null);
    }
}

function showXmlCustomerInfo(request, resultRegion) {
    if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)) {
        let xmlDocument = request.responseXML;
        let headings = getXmlValues(xmlDocument, "heading");
        let customers = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("customer");
        let rows = new Array(customers.length);
        let subElementNames =
            ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "balance"];
        for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = getElementValues(customers[i], subElementNames);
        }
        let table = getTable(headings, rows);
        htmlInsert(resultRegion, table);
    }
}

function getXmlValues(xmlDocument, xmlElementName) {
    let elementArray =
        xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName(xmlElementName);
    let valueArray = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
        valueArray[i] = getBodyContent(elementArray[i]);
    }
    return(valueArray);
}

function getBodyContent(element) {
    element.normalize();
    return(element.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}

function getElementValues(element, subElementNames) {
    let values = new Array(subElementNames.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < subElementNames.length; i++) {
        let name = subElementNames[i];
        let subElement = element.getElementsByTagName(name)[0];
        values[i] = getBodyContent(subElement);
    }
    return(values);
}

function getTable(headings, rows) {
    let table = "<table border='1' class='ajaxTable'>\n" +
        getTableHeadings(headings) +
        getTableBody(rows) +
        "</table>";
    return(table);
}

function getTableHeadings(headings) {
    let firstRow = "  <tr>";
    for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
        firstRow += "<th>" + headings[i] + "</th>";
    }
    firstRow += "</tr>\n";
    return(firstRow);
}

function getTableBody(rows) {
    let body = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        body += "  <tr>";
        let row = rows[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            body += "<td>" + row[j] + "</td>";
        }
        body += "</tr>\n";
    }
    return(body);
}

function htmlInsert(id, htmlData) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = htmlData;
}
```

**XML JSP**

```
<customers>
  <headings>
    <heading>Customer ID</heading>
    <heading>First Name</heading>
    <heading>Last Name</heading>
    <heading>Balance</heading>
  </headings>
  <customer>
    <id>${customers[0].getCustomerID()}</id>
    <firstName>${customers[0].getFirstName()}</firstName>
    <lastName>${customers[0].getLastName()}</lastName>
    <balance>${customers[0].getFormattedBalance()}</balance>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <id>${customers[1].getCustomerID()}</id>
    <firstName>${customers[1].getFirstName()}</firstName>
    <lastName>${customers[1].getLastName()}</lastName>
    <balance>${customers[1].getFormattedBalance()}</balance>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

Comment: Would be more helpful if you would point out exactly what line(s) the error is on.

Comment: You may need to set `request.responseType = 'document'; request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');` after `request.open` and before `request.send`. Get data then with `const xmlDocument = request.response;`, of course.

Comment: thanks @ScottMarcus. not quite sure I understand. there aren't any line numbers in the code snippets, so I'm not sure how I would do that? the error is pointing to the two js functions mentioned in the description. line numbers are 113 and 235..

Comment: @StackSlave that's worked! Brilliant, thanks so much. For my learning, could you explain why that's needed...and why it wasn't needed on localhost? Thanks again.

Comment: @StackSlave please post your comment that helped OP as an answer.

Comment: I'm curious to know why someone has marked this post down.

Answer (score 1):

Set `request.responseType = 'document'; request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');` after `request.open` and before `request.send`. Get data then with `const xmlDocument = request.response;`